# C# ASP.NET 4.8 Redirect working properly, but throws a http 403 error in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, cors-anywhere

I had to write a simple redirection endpoint in ASP.NET 4.8 which works fine, and now I have to rewrite it for ASP.NET Core 6.0.

Redirection endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
// GET: Redirect
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var externalLinks = _configuration.GetSection("ExternalLinks");

    string userAgent = Request.Headers["User-Agent"];

    if (userAgent.Contains("Android"))
    {
        return Redirect(externalLinks["PlayStore"]);
    }
    else if (userAgent.Contains("iPhone"))
    {
        return Redirect(externalLinks["AppStore"]);
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect(externalLinks["OtherDeviceUrl"]);
        //return Redirect("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://google.com");
    }
}
```

With `Program.cs` including:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{ endpoints.MapControllers(); });

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I keep encountering this error:

[Error with normal link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVWSV.png)

Also as you can see I've tried to use

```
return Redirect("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://google.com");
```

And I get an http 403 forbidden error instead.

Comment: Welcome to [so] please read the [tour] and [ask]. This seems to be a [sf] question related to herokuapp instead aspnet

Comment: When was last time old code worked?  Most people are moving Authentication from Windows Credentials to OAUTH 2.0.  CORS issues are usually due to Network Settings changes that you do not have rights to violate.  Updating from Net 4.8 to Net 6.0 should not of changed the authentication.  So I suspect your app hasn't been used in a while.

Comment: Using the provided code and some assumptions (like adding Route attribute and simplifying Index() logic) I had to make because it is not complete, I am receiving a proper 302 redirect. There's got to be a problem either with your server config or some small bug in code that is not shown in the question. Could you provide a broader insight into Program.cs?

Comment: @EmilKucharczyk  I left out only basic services and swagger :

'var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(); '

Comment: @jdweng today actually. I created seperate project from Net Core Web API using framework 6.0 and rewrote endpoint using slightly different syntax updating it for newer framework. I didn't have to do anything with Credentials or Authentication in net 4.8.0 tho. Redirects worked right away (rightfuly so).

Comment: Ok, just to make it clear. You are receiving a 403 from the server your code is running on, not from the server that your app redirects to, right?

Comment: @EmilKucharczyk Yeah. I've tried various websites as well. The default link is "https://www.google.com/". To my surprise "cors-anywhere" didn't work either, but it changed the error message to 403. I was wondering if it might be firewall or something, but disabling it didn't change a thing.

Comment: In such case, try comparing the requests from your .NET Framework and .NET apps. You can use Telerik Fiddler web debbuger (it's lightweight and free) to capture and save those requests to make comparison easier. Being able to compare these may make things easier if not obvious.

Comment: @EmilKucharczyk thanks, will try it out in a second. What's funny (probably irrelevant tho) is that when I set "launchUrl": from "swagger" to "https://www.google.com/" it opens Google page on run without any issues....

Comment: I think this is a cookie issue.   Old and new where from same client machine?  There is two possibilities 1) Old code worked because cookie allowed login.  Deleting cookies old code may stop working.  Authentication may of changed 2) New Code may start working after deleting cookies.

Comment: @EmilKucharczyk don't know if it's relevant but 4.8 Tunnels To HOST: www.google.com:443  , and 6.0 Tunnels To HOST: clients4.google.com:443

Comment: @jdweng removed all cookies, still doesn't work :/ I have no idea how something so simple can't work. No one nowhere seems to have such issues with a simple redirection lol

Comment: @EmilKucharczyk also the body when accessing via .net 4.8 has value of 45417 and via .net 6.0 61604. I would post them, but they are obviously too long for this feed, but maybe there is an issue...

Comment: Can you modify code to tunnel to old URL and see if code works?  I think the tunnel is a Proxy.  Default proxy setting may of changed.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619519/authenticate-with-azure-ad-using-aspnet-core-2-from-behind-corporate-proxy